# LIKE filtering of LCHR field in OData service

Tags: sql, odata, sap-gateway

I am developing a UI5 application consuming OData services with SAP Gateway, where I have implemented a search functionality which is producing an SQL *where* condition. One part of the condition looks like follows: `... OR DESCRIPTION LIKE '%searchString%'...` . In my database table, I have a field `DESCRIPTION` which is of type `LCHR` length `32000`. The only problem is that the field `DESCRIPTION` cannot be in `WHERE` clause.

What would be a correct approach of searching long strings in database table via OData services? Do I need to hardcode the search functionality or is there some cleaner way?

Comment: did you try passing this string to the frontend and do a high performing frontend search instead of passing odata requests back and forth? This means adding another field in your entity, containing your search string, and do a ui5 filtering? We did this and its performing very good.

Comment: `where I have implemented a search functionality which is producing a SQL where condition` how di you implemented it? give the current code

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [CDS Table Function](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abencds_f1_define_table_function.htm). The basic idea is to push the search down to HANA which is implemented by [AMDP](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenamdp_functions_abexa.htm). I did some local testing to answer this by concrete code.

I created a table `zza_test`

```
@EndUserText.label : 'TEST'
@AbapCatalog.enhancementCategory : #NOT_EXTENSIBLE
@AbapCatalog.tableCategory : #TRANSPARENT
@AbapCatalog.deliveryClass : #A
@AbapCatalog.dataMaintenance : #LIMITED
define table zza_test {
    key mandt : mandt not null;
    key bukrs : bukrs not null;
    cnt       : abap.int4;
    des       : abap.lchr(2000);
}
```

Defined a CDS table function `zza_test_tf` with parameter `search_str`.

```
@EndUserText.label: 'TEST TF'
define table function zza_test_tf
with parameters
    @Environment.systemField: #CLIENT
       clnt   :abap.clnt,
       search_str : char255
returns
{
    mandt : mandt;
    bukrs : bukrs;
    cnt   : abap.int4;
    des   : abap.lchr(2000);

}
implemented by method zcl_zza_test_tf=>search_des;
```

Created a Class `zcl_zza_test_tf` with interface `if_amdp_marker_hdb` and implement the method `search_des`

```
class zcl_zza_test_tf definition
public
final
create public .

public section.
  interfaces if_amdp_marker_hdb.
  class-methods search_des

      for table function zza_test_tf.
 endclass.

class zcl_zza_test_tf implementation.
   
   method search_des by database function for hdb
      language sqlscript
      options read-only
      using zza_test.
   
      return select mandt,bukrs, cnt, des
                from zza_test where des like concat( concat( '%', 
                   :search_str), '%');

   endmethod.

endclass.
```

Now we have a CDS table function with parameters. Run the CDS view and input the search parameter to get the result. You can even define your HANA SQL in your AMDP implementation with [fuzzy search](https://help.sap.com/viewer/691cb949c1034198800afde3e5be6570/2.0.01/en-US/cc602780bb5710148aa2bf6cab3c015b.html).

To fulfill the requirement, you implement the Open SQL select on this CDS view at your GateWay layer.

```
data:
    lt_test type standard table of ZZA_TEST_TF.

select * from ZZA_TEST_TF( search_str = 'DUM' ) into table @lt_test.
```

Everything should work. Hope it helps. Thank you!